# How to calculate data from different rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have following table to monitor the price each day, and I want to do calculation between two days like today's close price - previous day
s open price , e.g Thur's close - Wed's open, so I can see the difference.

Also, there is no records for the weekend, so how I can do 2 calculation different, 
e.g 1.  Mon's close - Sun returns same Mon price, 
    2. Mon's close price - previous Fri's open etc

```
INSERT INTO goods(date,day,open,high,low,close,`range(daily high- low)`) VALUES
 ('2018-11-01','Thu',1.08430,1.08766,1.08175,1.08285,0.00591),
 ('2018-11-02','Fri',1.08319,1.08585,1.07988,1.07988,0.00597),
 ('2018-11-05','Mon',1.08258,1.08389,1.08011,1.08155,0.00378),
 ('2018-11-06','Tue',1.08160,1.08489,1.07461,1.07469,0.01028),
 ('2018-11-07','Wed',1.07543,1.07646,1.07094,1.07150,0.00552),
 ('2018-11-08','Thu',1.07148,1.07571,1.07083,1.07393,0.00488),
 ('2018-11-09','Fri',1.07409,1.07651,1.07124,1.07125,0.00527),
 ('2018-11-12','Mon',1.07190,1.07389,1.06759,1.06878,0.00630),
 ('2018-11-13','Tue',1.06830,1.06977,1.06609,1.06658,0.00368)
```

Ideal output 1:

```
  date,         day, open,    high,   low,close, diff
 ('2018-11-01','Thu',1.08430,1.08766,1.08175,1.08285, ..
 ('2018-11-02','Fri',1.08319,1.08585,1.07988,1.07988, - 0.00442
 ('2018-11-05','Mon',1.08258,1.08389,1.08011,1.08155,- 0.00164
 ('2018-11-06','Tue',1.08160,1.08489,1.07461,1.07469,-0.00789
```

output 2:

```
  date,         day, open,    high,   low,close, diff
 ('2018-11-01','Thu',1.08430,1.08766,1.08175,1.08285, ..
 ('2018-11-02','Fri',1.08319,1.08585,1.07988,1.07988, - 0.00442
 ('2018-11-05','Mon',1.08258,1.08389,1.08011,1.08155, 1.08155
 ('2018-11-06','Tue',1.08160,1.08489,1.07461,1.07469,-0.00789
```

I am using php7.1, mysql

Comment: You are asking for a lot of code here.  Maybe you should focus on just one of your many suggested queries, and also show us your attempt for that query.  Also, please tell us which _version_ of MySQL you are using, as MySQL 8+ has a bunch of features which might make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: Why not provide table definitions too!?!?!?!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can use `LAG()` to access the immediate previous record, ordered by date. This will happily ignore gaps in days, so Monday closing price will be compared with Friday openning price :

```
SELECT
    g.*,
    g.close - LAG(g.open) OVER(ORDER BY g.date) price_diff
FROM goods g
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nnAXa9eZsdyHnJppGpGU8m/0)**

---

With older versions of MySQL, one would typically use a self-join and a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXISTS` condition to retrieve the previous record :

```
SELECT g.*, g.close - g1.open price_diff
FROM goods g
LEFT JOIN goods g1 
    ON g1.date < g.date
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM goods g2 WHERE g2.date < g.date AND g2.date > g1.date
    )
```

`g` is the current record (say : today). `g1` represents yesterday’s record : to identify it, we indicate the RDBMS that :

- `g1`'s date is lower than `g`'s date
- no record (`g2`) exists with a date lower than today’s (`g`) and higher than yesterday’s (`g1`)

The combination of these two conditions allows the RDMS to uniquely identify the relevant record (yesterday’s), whose value can then be used in the computation.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nnAXa9eZsdyHnJppGpGU8m/1)**

Comment: thanks @GMB, lag is not working for me, so i believe i am in a lower version of mysql, the second codes work for me, but don't understand how you did it, as i am a beginner

Comment: @coast666 : I updated my answer with more explanations.

Comment: thanks @GMB for your explanations, i will study your code further, thanks a lot indeed

Comment: @cast666 : if my answer properly responded to your question, please upvote/accept it, to indicate the community that it was helpful and solved your problem... Thanks !